# add <br/> and <hr/> to page in codebehind asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, newline, addition, code-behind

I am adding labels to the page programmaticaly(codebehind file c#)

```
Label label1 = new Label();
label1.Text = "abc";
this.Page.Form.FindControl("ContentPlaceHolder1").Controls.Add(label1);

Label label2 = new Label();
label2.Text = "def";
this.Page.Form.FindControl("ContentPlaceHolder1").Controls.Add(label2);
```

I want to add hr and br between these labels.How to do that?

```
this.Page.Form.FindControl("ContentPlaceHolder1").Controls.Add("<hr/>");
```

doesn't work.

Comment: "<hr/>" is not a control.  Add a `LiteralControl` instead

Answer (score 13, accepted):

```
Label label1 = new Label();
    label1.Text = "Test 1";
    form1.Controls.Add(label1);

    form1.Controls.Add(new Literal() { ID="row", Text="<hr/>" } );


    Label label2 = new Label();
    label2.Text = "Test 2";
    form1.Controls.Add(label2);

Output:
Test 1
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Test 2
```

Answer (score 7):

Add a [`LiteralControl`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.literalcontrol.aspx):

```
this.Page.Form.FindControl("ContentPlaceHolder1")
    .Controls.Add(new LiteralControl("<hr/>"));
```

Answer (score 7):

You could use a [HtmlGenericControl](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.htmlcontrols.htmlgenericcontrol.aspx)

```
 var hrControl = new HtmlGenericControl("hr")
 this.Page.Form.FindControl("ContentPlaceHolder1").Controls.Add(hrControl);
```

Comment: This causes a closing hr tag </hr> and will cause validation errors when HTML parsing with the HtmlAgilityPack. The same goes for other self closing tags. If you need a self closing tag you should use the appropriate HTML control or a Literal.

Answer (score 4):

you can use a literal control

```
Literal c = new Literal();
c.Text = "<hr />;
```